# How to make a 12V distribution block for hard drives

Tags: power-supply

I have six external hard drives with 12V transformer bricks.  I want to power them all from a single PSU to save space, weight, and power.  But I have two concerns about this approach:

1. If one drive shorts, it might short out all the other drives.
2. Multiple drives spinning up simultaneously might spike the voltage.

How to prevent those problems?

Comment: 1) Fuse, PTC, or electronic current limiting switch

Comment: 2) Sequence the spin-up by switching power to each drive individually. You are right to worry about this. Without this, you would need to design the supply for a much higher max power.

Comment: Sequencing is not always an option, it needs to be more foolproof. So oversizing the PSU would fix that?

Comment: Server psu do this all the time. 6 hard drives aren't even a bother

Answer (score 1):

Most power supplies have a continuous power allowed and a surge power for a short duration.  Select a power supply to have large enough values for both start up surge and normal full load of all drives.

To prevent shorts causing an issue, a PTC is probably the easiest.  These are devices that heat up as current flows through them.  They allow a certain level, but become high resistance (thus limiting current flow) when hitting 50% more than that level.  They will then reset when they cool down.  The surge current is fast enough that it will not trip the PTC, but a short would.  The PTC will pull as much as is needed to keep it in the shutoff region, but would not bring all drives down.